# Calling a Method from one class and used in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uibutton

I have the a method in ViewController to draw a button. In ViewController2 I want to call the method and draw the button out.

In ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(void)method;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)method{
    UIButton*Touch1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [Touch1 addTarget:self action:@selector(TouchButton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Touch1 setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50, 100, 100)];
    Touch1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    [Touch1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Touch1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:Touch1];

    NSLog(@"hi ");
}

-(void)TouchButton1:(UIButton*)sender{

    NSLog(@"hi again");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Then I am trying to call from ViewController2

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewController * ViewCon = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [ViewCon method];
}
```

The NSLog shows correct text but no button was created. 
What is my problem?

Thanks

Comment: plz add full details so i can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this problem is caused by the scope of "self" on the method "method". Your button has been added into de firstView and not in the secondView. To do what you whant, you will have to pass the scope that you like to add the button. Like the sample given by @trojanfoe.

```
-(void)method:(UIView *)_view {
    UIButton*Touch1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [Touch1 addTarget:self action:@selector(TouchButton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Touch1 setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50, 100, 100)];
    Touch1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    [Touch1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Touch1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [_view addSubview:Touch1];

    NSLog(@"hi ");
}
```

And into your second view you can call:

```
 ViewController * ViewCon = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[ViewCon method:self.view];
```

i think thats the problem, i hope that will help you

Comment: This is a terrible pattern as it's inefficient and inconvenient.

Comment: Create a class that will have your function,  is more reusable. If there is another part of your code that uses the same logic for implement that button, you can use the "utils" class and not use replicable code. But if your problem is an expecific issue that will be used just one time on your entire code, do an separated class is a more complex way to solve a simple problem. But do an category like @trojanfoe said on the final part of their answer is a smart solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate class (called `Utils`, for example) with a class method that can be called from both view controllers:

```
@implementation Utils

+(void)methodForView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIButton*Touch1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [Touch1 addTarget:self action:@selector(TouchButton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Touch1 setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50, 100, 100)];
    Touch1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    [Touch1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Touch1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [view addSubview:Touch1];
}

@end
```

And call it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [Utils methodForView:self.view];
}
```

Or better still, implement the method in a `UIViewController`-subclass and then derive all other view controllers from this base class.