# Reusing variables in other method file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables, uibutton

I have the following code to generate a UIBUtton from a method file called FirstViewController, since the location of the button will change in different secondviewController or thirdViewController, is it possible to set a variable for the location (CGRect) of the unbutton in the FirstViewController and change the CGRect Value in the second or third viewController?

In FirstViewController.m

```
     -(void)method:(UIView *)_view {

            UIButton*Touch1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [Touch1 addTarget:self action:@selector(TouchButton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [Touch1 setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50, 100, 100)];
            **//I want to set a variable for the CGRectMake**
            Touch1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
            [Touch1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Touch1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];
             [_view addSubview:Touch1];

            NSLog(@"test ");
        }
```

In SecondViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewController * ViewCon = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    **//Change variable here by defining the new CGRect here.**
    [ViewCon method:self.view];
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you just don't pass the `CGRect` value you want as a second parameter to `method:`? (And change the name of that method to something more descriptive, e.g. `makeButtonInView:withFrame:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is incorrect:

```
ViewController * ViewCon = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[ViewCon method:self.view];
```

as you are allocating a new view controller just to use one of its the method and then you are throwing the view controller instance away.  It's extremely inefficient and inconvenient.

Either move the method to a utility class, as a class method:

```
[Utils method:self.view rect:rect];
```

or subclass `UIViewController` and implement the method in that base class and then derive all similar view controllers from that base class, passing any variables into it.

```
[self method:rect];      // method implemented in MyBaseViewController
```

You also asked this [question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592815/calling-a-method-from-one-class-and-used-in-another-class) and accepted an answer that promotes the use of this bad pattern.  That will mislead others into using this bad pattern.